# How to delete an element via XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I need to stop the new-sat-grid.png image from this HTML file from displaying using XSLT when I output it to XML. How can I do that?

```
<section class="ktp-question-stem" data-uuid="2ede10d4ba5f46f8b9d40fb158ec5465">
  <p data-uuid="2087a4751e864674a726b905957a09cd">How many minutes
  will it take Daniel to spray all of the lawns in the
  neighborhood?</p>
  <img class="icon" src="../../img/chapter02/new-sat-grid.png" 
       data-graphic-ref="new-sat-grid.png"
       alt="new-sat-grid.eps"
       data-uuid="291dd9a095ad495bb9b191ced96714b7" />
</section>
<ol class="ktp-answer-set" 
    data-uuid="6b3025efceb341dd911e77e834714d98">
  <li property="ktp:answer" typeof="ktp:AnswerCorrect"
      data-uuid="acb5e012669042538256690d67bc29bd">60</li>
</ol>
<section property="ktp:feedback" typeof
         ="ktp:Feedback"
         class="ktp-feedback"
         data-uuid="5d6f009d0cfcf647b1134855aef7eb6e">
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with the identity transform and add a template that suppresses `img` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="img"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Explanation**: By default the identity transformation will copy everything over to the output as-is.  Override this default behavior by writing a simple template that matches `img` and does nothing, thereby preventing such elements from appearing in the output document.